# Unable to register/login new user account via manage email/password authentication (TypeError: Load failed)

Tags: mongodb, realm

I am working on a react application using realm Web SDK.

I have a register page with the email and password input fields. When submitting the credentials, I am faced with 'TypeError: Load failed' when catching the error.

To verify if my app is working, I have went to view my application app users, and no user entry is created. Have also done all checks such as making sure Email/Password authentication is enabled, and allowing automatic confirmation of users. My app has been set up properly, with my application ID.

Have even went to the extend of using the documentation example to register a new account, but I am still faced with the same error message:

```
const email = "someone@example.com";
const password = "Pa55w0rd!";
await app.emailPasswordAuth.registerUser({ email, password });
```

Taken from: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/web/manage-email-password-users/

Can anyone please advise on this issue? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: There could be 100 different causes; do you have email password auth *enabled* for the app in the Realm console? Does the email already exist? How about error handling? Are you getting a confirmation email? Did you check the logs in the Realm console? Please do some troubleshooting before posting questions - that can often be revealing but if not, include what you did so we have a clearer picture of the issue.

Comment: @Jay Appreciate your reply and thank you. However, I hope that in future, you will not assume that the questioner has not done the necessary troubleshooting. For your questions which you have included in your comment, they have already been answered in my original question.

Regardless, I have found the solution and included it in my question. Cheers and have a great day ahead!

Comment: We do not assume anything here on SO. We only work with data presented in the question and if more information is needed we request the question be updated to include that. Those were examples of the many things it could be; eliminating variables is very important when troubleshooting, hence the followup questions. It's great you have an answer; best practice here is to post answers as actual answers - and then you can accept your own answer! See [Answer My Own Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution:

For anyone who encounter the same problem as me:

**You need to include e.preventDefault().** By default, the browser will send the form data to the current URL and refresh the page. You can override that behaviour by calling e.preventDefault().

My data wasn't sent because this line wasn't called. Subsequently, read the form data with new FormData(e.target).

For example:

```
const onSubmit = async (e: any) => {
  try{
    e.preventDefault()
    const form = e.target;
    const formData = new FormData(form);
    const formJson = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());
    const user = await data.emailPasswordSignup(formJson.email, formJson.password);
    if (user) {
      redirectNow();
    }
  }
  catch (error) {
    alert(error);
  }
};
```

**Please read: https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/input**

Thanks for reading.